# Toggling the Draggable Points function in Highcharts not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, highcharts

I've been able to set up a Highcharts project with Draggable Points enabled, but what I would like to do now is to set it up so checking and unchecking a checkbox on the webpage will toggle the ability to move points around on the chart. To do this, I've set the **draggableX** and **draggableY** options to **false** when loading the chart:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        draggableX: false,
        draggableY: false,
        cursor: 'move'
     }
}
```

Later in the code, I've included a function that's called whenever the checkbox is checked or unchecked, like so, to change the settings on those two variables:

```
function enableDragging() {
    var checked = document.getElementById("enableDragging").checked;

    if (checked == true) {
        chart.options.plotOptions.series.draggableX = true;
        chart.options.plotOptions.series.draggableY = true;
    } else {
        chart.options.plotOptions.series.draggableX = false;
        chart.options.plotOptions.series.draggableY = false;
    }
}
```

(Note that "chart" is just the name of the variable for the chart in question.)

This isn't working as expected, though. When I load the page, draggableX and draggableY are set to false, as expected, and I'm unable to move points around on the chart. When I click on the checkbox, draggableX and draggableY are set to true, as expected, but I'm still unable to move the points around on the chart.

While testing, I've also set draggableX and draggableY to true when the charts load, and the behavior when clicking on the checkbox reverses itself. Points are editable from the start, and unclicking or clicking the checkbox successfully toggles those variables (as confirmed through the developer tools in the browser), but the points are still draggable.

So, it seems that I can edit the variables through the code, but that the chart will only remember what the variable was on load. Does anyone have any experience with this to know why the change doesn't stick?

Comment: I think that you need to use Series.update() method in case of your chart. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/sk3m3o7d/77/

Comment: Yes, that did it! I also had to move the toggle from the plotOptions section straight into the series. Thanks, Grzegorz!